# Is it possible to store numbers in form values?

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form, final-form

I am attempting to type a field to a number:

```
<Form
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
      initialValues={{ target_type_id: 1 }}
      render={({ handleSubmit, form, submitting, pristine, values }) => (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Field<number> name="target_type_id" type="radio" value={1}>
            {({ input }) => (
              <label>
                <input {...input} /> Alert
              </label>
            )}
          </Field>
          <Field<number> name="target_type_id" type="radio" value={2}>
            {({ input }) => (
              <label>
                <input {...input} /> Lookout
              </label>
            )}
          </Field>
          <Field<number> name="target_type_id" type="radio" value={3}>
            {({ input }) => (
              <label>
                <input {...input} /> Target
              </label>
            )}
          </Field>
          <Field<number> name="target_type_id" type="radio" value={4}>
            {({ input }) => (
              <label>
                <input {...input} /> Blitz
              </label>
            )}
          </Field>
          <pre style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            {JSON.stringify(values, undefined, 2)}
          </pre>
        </form>
      )}
    />
```

However, when I click on the radio buttons, the value captured is a string, so it doesn't ever match up to the numeric value specified in the `Field`

Any way I can capture values as a datatype other than string?

https://codesandbox.io/s/strongly-typed-form-values-with-react-final-form-forked-cvn4t?file=/src/index.tsx:918-2141

Comment: In html everything is a string. You can assign a number but when you retrive it it will be a string. But its simple you can convert it back do `let nun = Number(stringValue)`

Answer (score 0):

Get the value from the event and convert it into the number.

```
          <Field<number> name="target_type_id" type="radio" value={3}>
            {({ input }) => (
              <label>
                <input {...input} onChange={(e) => input.onChange(Number(e.target.value))} /> Target
              </label>
            )}
          </Field>
```

Comment: @TheFool What do you mean?

Comment: look at the profile of op. 15k rep and top tag is javascript. Someone like that would never ever have to ask the question. Even if they didnt know what was going on, which they really should, they would still most certainly know how to convert a string to a number.

Comment: Their profile shows 173 posts in javascript with score of 279.  Its just extremely unlikely, I don't mind someone not beeing as knowledgeable yet but this scenario here is just surreal.

Comment: Shows that even mighty could fall, aye.